How old was Shmuel in Perek 3
In the Artscroll notes of Shmuel 1 to the beginning Perek 3, they say (quoting Seder Olam) that one would assume Shmuel I young during this episode, but that he was actually around 40
First of all, how does this fit with the fact that he’s called a נער in pasuk 1? Also, in the next Artscroll note they then say that Shmuel wasn’t old enough to help with the temple service. How is this so if they also say he was 40?

Josephus (Book V, Chapter 10:4) states that Samuel was 12 when he began to prophesy (in 1 Shmuel, Chapter 3)

Now when Samuel was twelve years old, he began to prophesy: and once
when he was asleep, God called to him by his name; and he, supposing
he had been called by the high priest, came to him: but when the high
priest said he did not call him, God did so thrice.


Interesting and makes sense but doesn’t really answer my question
